# Retrive Quantite depand on type SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a VenPro table with Four Column Reference, Type, Qty, and Value in column type ago either production is selling
I want to retrieve the Product Reference and their Qty Sold and Qty Produced and their value with the condition that there is a sale. For example if I have a product of qte for type prodution is 5 and there is no sales qte I do not want it to be displayed

Table VenPro

```
 ----------------------------
    Ref + Type   + Qty+ Value +
    -----------------------------
    01  +   Prod + 10 + 100   +
    02  +   Prod + 05 + 50    +
    02  +   Sale + 03 + 45    +
    03  +   Prod + 8  + 80    +
    03  +   Sale + 8  + 120   +
    ---------------------------
```

The query must show the reference product lines 02 and 03 because there is a Prod and Sale quantity and do not display row 01 because there is no sale.

As its going back that lines Sale this I'm looking for

```
--Production ---- + ------- Sale
Ref + Qty + Value +--+ Qty + Value +
-------------------------------------+
02  + 05  + 50    +--+  03  + 45     +
03  + 8   + 80    +--+  8   + 120    +
-------------------------------------+
```

view line Pro / Sale without ref 01 because there is no sale

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's a query you are looking for. I assume that [VenPro] is correct table name.

```
select o.Ref, o.Qty, o.Value 
from o.[VenPro] o
where Type = 'Prod' and exists ( 
  select 1 from [VenPro] i where i.Type = 'Sale' and i.Ref = o.Ref );
```

Update:

```
select o.Ref, o.Qty, o.Value , i.Qty, i.Value
from o.[VenPro] o join [VenPro] i 
  on i.Type = 'Sale' and i.Ref = o.Ref and o.Type = 'Prod';
```

This should select combined details for Prod and Sale rows.

Comment: This will show only production and not show Sale with production

Comment: @Supupoff I added an update. Hope it's what you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the update thats what i lookin for but Qte and Value show are incorrect is like recurrent collect same Qte

Answer (score 0):

this problem can also be solved by using sub-query

```
with cte1 as (
    select * from VenPro v where Type = 'Prod'
), cte2 as
(
 select * from VenPro v1 where Type = 'Sale'
) 
 select cte1.*  from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.Ref=cte2.Ref
```